# how to create int to string like this 50-> "00050"

Tags: c#

Hello i am trying to process character arrays.
I want to assign the number 50 as string value "00050". How can I do it ?

```
enter code here
 string strRpc(int NumstrRpcSendLen)
    {
        int digit =  Convert.ToInt32( Math.Floor(Math.Log10(NumstrRpcSendLen + 5) + 1));
        int len = 0;
        char[] d = new char[5];
        string result= null;


        while (len<5)
        {
            if (len<digit)
            {
                d[len] = '0';
            }
            else
            {




            }

            len++;
        }

        return result;

       }
```

Comment: Um, `string text = number.ToString("00000");`? No need to do all this manually. I'd also strongly advise learning about .NET naming conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your code is doing, but there's a string format specifier for that:

```
var x = 50.ToString("D5");
//x = "000050"
```

[Look at the documentation for more help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could try it

```
var result = 50.ToString("00000");
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, one should always add an explanation why/how the problem is solved.